# Unable to start tomcat 8 on ubuntu 16.0.4 TLS

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat

I have written an application on REST API's and deployed that on tomcat 8.0.36. When I start the application from eclipse it gives me a timeout message after 45 seconds "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."
I have done all the troubleshooting stuff:
1) Deleted the server from the server perspective and re-added the server and tried to re-deploy it
2) get the same message as above.
3) I have tried by launching the tomcat without the application deployed it starts .

Regards
Vilas

Comment: Any message from logs or console?

Answer (score 0):

To increase the tomcat boot time, you must follow the following steps:

1. Launch **Eclipse**
2. On **`Servers`** view, double click on you tomcat server configuration
3. Find the option **`Timeouts`**, this is in the top right of editor
4. Increase the time, for example **`120`**.

[image: *Look at the picture*]